# how to insert text without any spacing wrt borders in rich text box field

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

[image: no margins required, have tried style border, margin, display everything]

Have used a rich text box and no margins are required, have tried style border, margin, display everything but still not working. Have to remove only the margin from each end.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, are you able to create a mock-up in an image editing program to show the result that you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexTennant   - The text which I have written in the box is in center and 20px margin is there wrt box. Have to remove this margin